# How to set .NET Core in #if statement for compilation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I created a multi-targeted framework project. I use something like this:

```
  #if NET40
    Console.WriteLine("Hello from .NET Core 4");
  #endif
```

But I can't find a wildcard for .NET Core. I tried:

```
   #if NETCOREAPP1.0
     Console.WriteLine("Hello from .NET Core");
   #endif
```

But it is not valid statement.

Comment: Change to `#if NETCOREAPP1_0`

Comment: Yes, replace `.` with `_`

Comment: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if) msdn lists the predefined .net core symbols.

Answer (score 92):

You need an underscore, `_`, instead of a point:

`NETCOREAPP1_0` or the more recent `NETCOREAPP1_1` and `NETCOREAPP2_0`

The documentation for *[Target frameworks in SDK-style projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks)* includes a list for the different preprocessor symbols.

##### .NET Framework

`NETFRAMEWORK, NET48, NET472, NET471, NET47, NET462, NET461, NET46, NET452, NET451, NET45, NET40, NET35, NET20`

##### .NET Standard

`NETSTANDARD, NETSTANDARD2_1, NETSTANDARD2_0, NETSTANDARD1_6, NETSTANDARD1_5, NETSTANDARD1_4, NETSTANDARD1_3, NETSTANDARD1_2, NETSTANDARD1_1, NETSTANDARD1_0`

##### .NET 5+ and .NET Core

`NET, NET6_0, NET6_0_ANDROID, NET6_0_IOS, NET6_0_MACOS, NET6_0_MACCATALYST, NET6_0_TVOS, NET6_0_WINDOWS, NET5_0, NETCOREAPP, NETCOREAPP3_1, NETCOREAPP3_0, NETCOREAPP2_2, NETCOREAPP2_1, NETCOREAPP2_0, NETCOREAPP1_1, NETCOREAPP1_0`

##### Mono

For Mono you can usually use the NetFramework monikers known by your version of Mono. For instance, Mono 6.12 includes all NetFramework versions from 2.0 to 4.8. But if you must recognise Mono per se, then `MONO` and `__MonoCS__` should both be defined.

Comment: You can define `NETCOREAPP` and `NETSTANDARD` without its version. I test it and It works in VS2019.

Comment: For .NET 5 it ``NET5_0``
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks

Answer (score 38):

Extension of [Devon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38476796/how-to-set-net-core-in-if-statement-for-compilation/45963609#45963609) for Visual Studio 2017 .csproj files:

Looking at the table [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#supported-target-framework-versions), you can easily define constants by using regular expressions. So you don't need to think about updating the conditions if target frameworks are added/changed.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::IsMatch('$(TargetFramework)', '^net\d'))">
  <DefineConstants>NETFRAMEWORK</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::IsMatch('$(TargetFramework)', '^netstandard\d'))">
  <DefineConstants>NETSTANDARD</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::IsMatch('$(TargetFramework)', '^netcoreapp\d'))">
  <DefineConstants>NETCORE</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Usage:

```
#if NETFRAMEWORK
    FrameworkSpecific();
#endif

#if NETSTANDARD
    StandardSpecific();
#endif

#if NETCORE
    CoreSpecific();
#endif
```

Comment: good idea; it is a shame that these NETFRAMEWORK / NETSTANDARD / NETCORE symbols are not available as a standard part of the compiler

Comment: you should primarily write code that runs everywhere, without relying on compiler flags. this approach is only there for the rare case you really need it.

Comment: @gallivantor [Seems like they are now](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/2072) (except the symbol for .NET Core is called `NETCOREAPP`)

Comment: I think this ([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::IsMatch('$(TargetFramework)', '^net\d'))) statement give wrong result for .net5.0 and .net 6.0

Answer (score 13):

You can define any custom conditional compilation symbols in the following way (project.json):

```
"frameworks": {
    "net40": {
      "buildOptions": {
        "define": ["NET_40"]
      }
    },
    "netstandard1.5": {
      "buildOptions": {
        "define": [ "NET_STANDARD" ]
      }

    }
}
```

This approach seems to be more practical because you may use the same conditional symbol for several targets, without need to write something like

```
#if NET20 && NET 40 && NET45
```

Comment: where do you define the .net standard projects? Can you update your answer to show using multiple targets

Comment: At the time this was posted, it was correct.  But MS has moved away from project.json files to .csproj files.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/migration/

Answer (score 7):

For the new Visual Studio 2017 .csproj project system, you can find the full list of available symbols in *[Developing Libraries with Cross Platform Tools, How to Multitarget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/libraries#how-to-multitarget)*.

You can create composite constant(s) for it in your .csproj file like so:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net451' Or '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net461' ">
    <DefineConstants>FULLFRAMEWORK;FULL</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Then you can use it in a `#if` compiler directive like so:

```
#if FULLFRAMEWORK
        private bool DoSomethingFullFrameworkSpecific()
        {
            var connectionStringSetting = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionStringName];
            return connectionStringSetting != null;
        }
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

While [Vitaliy Fedorchenko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38476796/how-to-set-net-core-in-if-statement-for-compilation/38482101#38482101) is correct, it should be noted that there is a bug in the .NET Core xproj project type. When you define a conditional compilation symbol through the project settings, it defines the element as "defines", but this is incorrect. It should create an element called "define". You can work around the issue by editing the project.json file manually.

I have logged this bug with Microsoft in two places. Please take the time to register your annoyance with Microsoft so that they eventually get around to fixing it and not causing this grief for others.

This thread has a detailed explanation of the problem with steps to reproduce, and screenshots:

*[3 Issues with NET Core Visual Studio Projects #4022](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/4022#issuecomment-238777946)*

This is the Microsoft Connect bug report:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/2983351/conditional-compilation-symbols-broken-in-net-core-projects#tabs

Comment: Microsoft has stopped the support for xproj and project.json in Vs2017

Comment: The second link is (effectively) broken: *"Microsoft Connect Has Been Retired"*. In any case, perhaps it is time for an update? (Note: the result should ***not*** be littered with "Edit:" or "Update: " (historical account of the answer itself), but as if the answer was written today, like *"Until version this of that it had problem X, and it was fixed 2018-01-31 in version ExtraGood. In Visual Studio 2017, this was replaced with Y."*)