# Define configuration dependent compiler symbol?

Tags: asp.net-core, conditional-compilation

I have read [Conditional Compilation symbol for .Net Core Class Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38040466/conditional-compilation-symbol-for-net-core-class-library) but this is about a different problem.

How can I, in Asp.Net core set a compiler symbol for the Debug configuration and a different one for the Release configuration?

The Configuration/Platform selection row is greyed out:
[image: greyed out config choice]

Selecting a different solution configuration in the VS toolbar doesn't make a difference either.